# Init has been renamed to init(describing) error in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

This code works fine in Swift 2:

```
guard let userData = responseData["UserProfile"] as? [String : AnyObject] else { return }

var userProfileFieldsDict = [String: String]()
if let profileUsername = userData["Username"] as? NSString {
  userProfileFieldsDict["username"] = String(profileUsername)
}
if let profileReputationpoints = userData["ReputationPoints"] as? NSNumber {
  userProfileFieldsDict["reputation"] = String(profileReputationpoints)
}
```

But, in `Swift 3` it throws an error on `userProfileFieldsDict["reputation"]` saying

> init has been renamed to init(describing:)

My question is why does it trigger on that line and not on the `userProfileFieldsDict["username"]` assignment line, and how to go about fixing it? I'm assuming it's because I'm casting a `NSNumber` to a `String`, but I can't really understand why that matters.

Comment: An `NSNumber` can store all sorts of numbers (`Float`, `Double`, `Int`, even `Bool`) – what do you expect the string representation to look like?

Answer (score 11):

[NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumber) is a very generic class. It can be anything from a `bool` to a `long` to even a `char`. So the compiler is really not sure of the exact data type hence it's not able to call the right String constructor.

Instead use the `String(describing: )` constructor as shown below

```
userProfileFieldsDict["reputation"] = String(describing: profileReputationpoints)
```

Here's more [info](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/2427941-init) about it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to drop your use of Objective-C types. This was always a bad habit, and now the chickens have come home to roost. Don't cast to NSString and NSNumber. Cast to String and to the actual numeric type. Example:

```
if let profileUsername = userData["Username"] as? String {
    userProfileFieldsDict["username"] = profileUsername
}
if let profileReputationpoints = userData["ReputationPoints"] as? Int { // or whatever
    userProfileFieldsDict["reputation"] = String(profileReputationpoints)
}
```